# How to grant to stored procedure, privileges to select from a different schema?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, schema, sql-grant

I need that the user does not have access to another scheme, but the stored procedure could access a different schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing is not possible.

If `b.procedure` can select, insert, update or delete on `a.table`, then anyone logged in as `b` could do so too.

What you should do instead is create procedure `a.procedure` and `grant execute on a.procedure to b`.

Answer (score 3):

Privileges cannot be granted to objects, only to users or roles.

The way to implement this granularity of control is for the other schema to define the procedure which operates on its own tables.  It then grants execute on the procedure to the other user.  This is one valuable use case for procedures, encapsulating operations on schema objects.

The mechanism for controlling privileges in PL/SQL objects is the AUTHID.  There are two options, CURRENT_USER and DEFINER.  In this case you want to use the definer's rights, `AUTHID DEFINER` (which is the default).  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#sthref717).

Comment: Definer's rights is/are the default, why confuse this answer by even mentioning it?

Comment: @Colin'tHart - for the sake of completeness